# Pre-populate main search field with desired phrase?

Tags: search

I'm looking to create a URL that opens up a salesforce search with my desired phrase

In google this is pretty simple if you wanted to search "opposum" you would just add your search phrase at the end of the google search string

so from this

http://www.google.com/search?q=

to this

http://www.google.com/search?q=opposum

Is there anyway to do the same thing in salesforce?

Answer (score 0):

Is the search you are looking for based on a field value? if so you can look at https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/lex_customization/lex_customization_buttons_links for an example of merging fields.